# Python XML getting all tags of name "X"

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file looking something like:

```
<a>
   <b>
       <c>
       </c>
   </b>
   <d>
       <e>
           <f>Value</f>    <!-- I want to extract this -->
       </e>
   </d>
   <d>
       <e>
           <f>Value2</f>   <!-- and this -->
       </e>
   </d>
   .
   .
   .
```

I am trying to use the following Python code to retrieve all data from the  nodes, i.e. Value1, Value2..... Is my understanding correct here?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')

for elem in tree.iterfind('a/d/e/f'):
     print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

However, I am just getting an empty loop. I have also tried findall() using online examples but getting nowhere. I just want to verify I am understanding their capabilities correctly.

Comment: If you turn that XML fragment into a complete doc (which may just be a matter of adding `</a>` at the end), this would be easier to debug. Even better, put the XML in a string in the source and change your example to use that instead of a file, and then you'd have a perfect [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your XPath starts off looking for an `a` child node under the root—but the root *is* the `a` node, and the `b` and `d` nodes are its children.

You can see this if you just print things out:

```
>>> print(tree)
<Element 'a' at 0x10bbe4bd8>
>>> print(tree.getchildren())
[<Element 'b' at 0x10bf8e318>,
 <Element 'd' at 0x10bf8ef98>,
 <Element 'd' at 0x10be1e818>]
```

What you probably want is this:

```
for elem in tree.iterfind('d/e/f'):
```

Or, as pointed out by Tim in the comments, if your `tree` is the result of parsing a file rather than the root of the tree, you’ll want to do this:

```
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.iterfind(‘d/e’f’):
```

Comment: I'm getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    print(tree.getchildren())
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getchildren'

Comment: @user997112 Well, this is exactly why an [mcve] is important. It works in the example I created by guessing at what your code is doing, but I apparently guessed wrong.

Comment: The issue here from your Traceback is that `ElementTree` objects don't have children, but `Element` objects do. So you need to build the tree and then get the root element to use `getchildren()`.

I imagine abarnert was using `tree = ET.fromstring(...)` which builds the tree and returns the root element, whereas user997112 is using `tree = ET.parse('file.xml')`. 

Really you should either do:
`root = ET.fromstring(xml_file_as_a_string)`
OR:
`tree = ET.parse('file.xml')` then `root = tree.getroot()`